# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "relativedelta") to str

Tags: python

i'm trying to get next month from selected date. if i using datetime.date.today() its ok. but i need working with request date. how can i solve it.Thanks

```
date = request.form['date']
print(date) // 2022-11-05
// nextmonth = datetime.date.today() + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
nextmonth = date + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert str to `date` and then use `relativedelta.relativedelta`.

Not sure what format the date is, I am assuming it is YYYY-MM-DD.

You can change the day and month format as per what you want.

```
import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta
date = '2022-11-05'
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
nextmonth = date + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
```

That should give you `2022-12-05`.